# Como insertar datos y crear tablas en Java Derby JDCB

Tags: java, base-de-datos, eclipse-oxygen, derby

Estoy tratando de realizar un programa para chequeo de ingreso de empleados
utilizo el driver Derby en eclipse oxygen.
Leyendo me tope con cierta informacion y se me hizo muy similiar a php y prepared statements, mi problematica es que al correr mi codigo se creo la base de datos, pero no puedo escribir en ella:

```
 PreparedStatement tableCrt = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE 
 TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbEmpleados(id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY 
 KEY,nombre varchar(225) NOT NULL ,password varchar(225),fechareg 
 varchar(27))");
 tableCrt.executeUpdate();
 tableCrt.close();
```

Realmente estoy perdido en Java y no se como continuar, este es el script de mi conexion.

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class tableCreation {
private static final String DRIVER = 
"org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"; 
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:EvCo- 
RegHuella;create=true";
Connection conn;

public tableCreation() {

    try {
        //tomamos la conexion y le pasamos la url
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        //si this.conn NO es nulo....
        if (this.conn != null) { 
            //SECCION EDITADA ------------------
            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement("TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbEmpleados ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL,Apellidos varchar(255) NOT NULL, Puesto varchar(255) NOT NULL,FechaReg varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID),");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();





        }


        //este es el catch del try nos va a tirar una SQLException en caso que falle la conexion
    }catch(SQLException e) {


        System.out.print("Fallo la conexion :( comprueba sintaxis o bien si el url esta correcto");

    } 

}
}
```

En la main activity solo llame :

```
     tableCreation conectNcreate = new tableCreation() ;
```

como comente al inicio la base de datos fue creada correctamente (lo veo incluso en mi directorio) lo que no veo es que se agregue informacion a ella, no se crea la tabla ni puedo agregar usuarios ni contraseña, de ante mano muchisimas gracias.

Comment: este es el SQL exeption que recibi  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "NOT" at line 1, column 17.Fallo la Creacion de la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni el "if not exist" ni el "auto increment" forman parte del sintaxis para crear tablas via Derby.
Te paso la liga del sintaxis de Derby para crear tablas:

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html

Para usar algo similar al "auto increment", te paso esta liga que es una sub parte de la liga anterior que te anexé.

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html#rrefsqlj37836

Ahora que comentas que no puedes agregar información, pero no estás mostrando el código que usas para agregar información.

La tabla que quieres crear la pude crear pero con este comando:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps =
                this.conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE APP.dbEmpleados (ID int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), Nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL,Apellidos varchar(255) NOT NULL, Puesto varchar(255) NOT NULL,FechaReg varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))");
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Nótese que el nombre de la tabla le puse APP.dbEmpleados, porque la creé en el schema APP, tú le puedes cambiar el esquema al que uses.

Saludos.